# Why there is no release date or timestamp in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I do not understand why there is no support for timestamp or some other release date metadata in `setup.py`. I looked into Python's documentation on [Writing the Setup Script](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) and Setupdools [User Guide](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) and found no support.

How one can release packages with explicit release date in metadata? And if that is deliberately unsupported, than why ?

Comment: You can apply [Calendar Versioning (Date based schema)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Date_of_release) if you would prefer to use date. Date based release segments are also permitted under PEP 440.

Comment: @buran Thanks. Yes calendar versining is an option. Albeit I do not want do change versioning schema of already existig packages. My original intent was just to add timestamp metadata.